# Python/Pandas: How to fill in blank spaces within my dataframe?

Tags: arrays, pandas, nan, spaces

I've already used `X = X.fillna(X.mean())` to fill in the `NaN`'s. But I still get an error

> "ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [  7
>   210]"

when I try my train_test_split.

I looked at my X df and it seems there are still values missing (blank spaces).

How do I fill those blank spaces with the mean of that column for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B': [6,7,8,np.nan,10]})
   A     B
0  1   6.0
1  2   7.0
2  3   8.0
3  4   NaN
4  5  10.0

print(df.B.fillna(df['B'].mean()))
0     6.00
1     7.00
2     8.00
3     7.75
4    10.00
Name: B, dtype: float64
```